# elegant way of replacing null with moving average in window

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, data-preprocessing

I have a time-series data that is represented in dataframe format, as follows:

```
U1  U2  U3  U4  U5  U6  U7  U8  U9  U10  U11  U12  U13  U14  U15  U16 ... U96
1   2   3   null 4  5   6   7   8   9    10   11   12   13   14   15  ...  95
...
```

As can be seen that `U4` has a null value and I want to replace it with the mean of 6 nearby values:`U1`, `U2`, `U3`, `U5`, `U6`, `U7`(three values ahead and three values afterward, if `U1` contains null, then 6 values afterward. If `U2` contains null, then 1 value ahead and 5 values afterward. etc.)

I can achieve it manullay like following:

```py
for i in range(len(df)):
    for j in range(1,97):
        if df.iat[i,j] == None:
           if j == 1:
                df.iat[i,j] = df._get_value(i,2) + df._get_value(i,3) + df._get_value(i,4) + ...
           elif j == 2:
                df.iat[i,j] = df.get_value(i,1) + df.get_value(i,3) + df.get_value(i,4) + ...
           elif j == 3:
                df.iat[i,j] = df.get_value(i,1) + df.get_value(i,2) + df.get_value(i,4) + ...
           else: 
                df.iat[i,j] = df.get_value(i,j-3) + df.get_value(i,j-2) + df.get_value(i,j-1) + ...
```

Is there a more elegant way of achieving this?